# Enviar posts de sites Wordpress parceiros para meu site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Boa noite.

Preciso desenvolver um plugin para Wordpress que funciona pegando o post publicado no site onde o plugin está instalado (que é de um site parceiro que fornece conteúdo) e enviando os campos do post (título, imagem de destaque, autor, conteúdo, tags...) para outro site Wordpress, em outro provedor/banco de dados, que será usado para alimentar um aplicativo para celular. Tem como fazer isso? Já existe algum plugin ou função que faça algo parecido ou tenho que começar do zero? Desenvolver um plugin para fazer isso é a melhor solução, ou existem outras?

Obrigada,

Mey

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma tabela no banco de dados que guarda os posts (não lembro o nome da tabela, mas acho que é algumacoisaPosts). Basta passar esses dados pro outro banco...

Comment: E é simples fazer isso? Desculpa a ignorância, mas é a primeira vez que vou fazer isso, e estou aprendendo php agora.

Comment: você usa phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Sim, uso phpMyAdmin

Comment: vê se você acha essa tabela posts, depois abre ela e clica na aba "exportar", ai ele vai fazer download do arquivo .sql com todos dados da sua tabela.

Comment: Entendi, mas no meu caso, eu não tenho acesso direto ao banco de dados onde os posts foram criados, pois são de outros sites parceiros que vão fornecer o conteúdo para minha aplicação. Por isso eu precisava de um plugin que esses parceiros instalariam e, cada vez que eles publicasse um novo post, este iria para o meu banco de dados.
A minha dúvida é qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso, se é criando um plugin, ou widget. Ou se já existe algum plugin que já faça isso. E qual o método/função que tenho que usar pra fazer isso.

Comment: Não sei se existe plugins, aconselho dar uma pesquisada.. 
se não achar, existe a possibilidade de eles fazerem uma página que fornece as informações dos posts (ex: posts.php) e você acessar essa página, pegar as informações e gravar no seu banco..